# How to upgrade tensorflow code from 1.0.0 to 2.0 fro google colab?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

Google Colab uses TF 2.0, my code was built using TF 1.0. Is there a way to run this code on google colab?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to avoid converting the code

```
! pip uninstall tensorflow
! pip install tensorflow==1.0
```

will always works, or if you want the code to be able to run at the tf 2.0, check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate) to do the code migration

Comment: and dont forget to restart your runtime